# How to create an object of List from another class in main method?

Tags: java, list, object, methods, main-method

I have to create an Object of List in main Method but i have no idea how to do it. Constructor of class, that i want to create an Object has an List as a parameter.

How can i create an Object of CashMachine class?

By the way I am not going to write all of the classes, because it is long.

Here are my classes:

```
    public class CashMachine {
        private State state;
        List<Account> accountList;
        private CashCard cashCard;
        private Account selectedAccount;

        public CashMachine(List<Account> accountList){
            this.accountList = accountList;
        }
    }

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CashMachine cashMachineObj = new CashMachine(); //it is false

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a `List<Account>` type argument in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a constructor, that wants a List ... so surprise, you have to provide one.

Simple, will compile, but is wrong:

```
CashMachine cashMachineObj = new CashMachine(null);
```

Better:

```
CashMachine cashMachineObj = new CashMachine(new ArrayList<>());
```

The above simply creates an *empty* list and passes that into the CashMashine.

In other words: there are many ways to create lists; and you can pick whatever approach you like. Even things like:

```
CashMachine cashMachineObj = new CashMachine(Arrays.asList(account1, account2));
```

where account1, account2 would be existing Objects of the Account class.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [docs for `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you will see that `List` is actually an interface!

Interfaces are like protocols. The methods in interfaces don't have implementations. The classes that implement the interface must provide those implementations. You can't just create a new `List` object by calling its constructor because it doesn't make sense to create an object with methods that have no implementations!

What you should do is to create an object of a class that implements `List`, for example, `ArrayList`.

```
 ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can now pass `accounts` to the constructor of `CashMachine`.